# Unable to establish the new service connection in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a new service connection and I'm facing the below error . Can someone please help.

```
Exception Message: Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Pipelines.PipelineValidationException (type ReleaseManagementHandledException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.DeployPhaseOrchestrator.FailOrchestrationImplementation(Int32 releaseId, Int32 releaseStepId, Nullable`1 releaseDeployPhaseId, Action`3 rejectStep, Exception ex) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\DeployPhaseOrchestrator.cs:line 243
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.DeployPhaseOrchestrator.FailOrchestration(Int32 releaseId, Int32 releaseStepId, Nullable`1 releaseDeployPhaseId, Exception ex) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\DeployPhaseOrchestrator.cs:line 232
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.DeployPhaseOrchestrator.InvokeRunner(Release release, ReleaseEnvironmentStep deployStep, ReleaseEnvironment releaseEnvironment, DeployPhaseSnapshot snapshotToProcess, Func`5 runDeployPhase, Action`4 acceptStep, Action`3 rejectStep, Action`4 handleException) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\DeployPhaseOrchestrator.cs:line 493
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.DeployPhaseOrchestrator.ProcessDeployPhasesImplementation(Release release, ReleaseEnvironmentStep deployStep, Func`5 runDeployPhase, Action`4 acceptStep, Action`3 rejectStep, Action`4 handleException) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\DeployPhaseOrchestrator.cs:line 122
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.DeployPhaseOrchestrator.ProcessDeployPhases(Release release, ReleaseEnvironmentStep deployStep) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\DeployPhaseOrchestrator.cs:line 70
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Server.Processors.OrchestratorServiceProcessorV2.ExecuteDeployStep(Release release, ReleaseEnvironmentStep releaseEnvironmentStep) in D:\v2.0\P1\_work\7\s\ReleaseManagement\Service\ReleaseManagement2\Server\Processors\OrchestratorServiceProcessorV2.cs:line 1178
```